# How to initialize new object with a data type List<T>?

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in C# and I want to initialize a new object which contains the datatype string as well a data type list<> from a enumeration. How does the structure/semantics looks like if I put a List into a new object ?
Thank you for your help.

I have searched on stackoverflow and also on MSDN and didn't found a proper solution.

This is my code:

```
Vegetables Veg1 = new Vegetables("Apple", List<Colour>("red, green, yellow"));
```

Comment: Avoid using http://Disney.com search for searching for programming questions. Google or https://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+initialize+list would do much better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Vegetables` type has a constructor that matches those arguments, and you really want three strings in the new list, you would write the line like this:

```
Vegetables Veg1 = new Vegetables("Apple", new List<string> {"red", "green", "yellow" });
```

or like this, if you mean to use `System.Drawing.Color`:

```
Vegetables Veg1 = new Vegetables("Apple", new List<Color> {Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Yellow });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped. Your second code was the solution :).